# OpenEdX, IRONWOOD - issues in redirection

Tags: openedx

I have installed OpenEdx in our AWS server today and have started playing around this awesome tool. But while playing around this Vanilainstallation, it is found that some of the links are still going to localhost. Is this expected (in my previous installation some links were going to an unknown server)?

**Note**: I have posted this OpenEdX forum, but not getting any responses.

Comment: Which links are going to the localhost? Studio URL, Preview URL, Analytics etc? Then you have to edit "lms.env.json & cms.env.json" and add your host URL, example.com, studio.example.com, preview.example.com.

Comment: @IsankaWijerathne I have checked the "lms.env.json". I m seeing a number of keys with value "localhost". Say for example: ANALYTICS_API_URL, ANALYTICS_DASHBOARD_URL. BASE_COOKIE_DOMAIN etc. Do I need to change all localhost references with IP?

Comment: Not necessary all. As you have mentioned that you are just "playing", It depends on what you want to change. Usually, when it goes production we do change these things(not sure all variables there), ANALYTICS_DASHBOARD_NAME 
BASE_COOKIE_DOMAIN 
CMS_BASE 
SITE_NAME 
LMS_BASE 
LMS_ROOT_URL 
CROSS_DOMAIN_CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN 
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN

Comment: @IsankaWijerathne Thanks. the following are the issues I'm facing currently.
1**.Trying to logout from studio**, it will be redirected to http://edx.devstack.lms:18000/logout
2.sign up in studio
http://localhost:18000/register?next=http%3A%2F%2F13.127.11.217%3A18010%2F
3.sign in studio
http://localhost:18000/login?next=http%3A%2F%2F13.127.11.217%3A18010%2Fdio -
4.while clicking view live button in studio
http://localhost:18000/courses/course-v1:edX+DemoX+Demo_Course/jump_to/block-v1:edX+DemoX+Demo_Course+type@course+block@course

Comment: @IsankaWijerathne. Sorry formatting is not allowed in the comment box and apologies for creating any confusion by using the "word playing around". My only intention was to say that I'm new to EdX and trying to do things using a trial and error method and with available documentation. Thank You

Comment: It seems you are using the Open edX devstack version. Isn't it? with this set up I do not think that you can have production like env. Try to install Open edX native installation. 
But anyway answer to your question is, you have to change the values of those Keys, that I posted previously.

Comment: @IsankaWijerathne Thanks a lot for your suggestions. Finally, we are able to complete Open edX native installation., with the help of ansible scripts As you know, the current EdX documentation is assuming some expertise that was lacking at his moment. Your comments helped us a lot to fill this gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Note: Posting the comments from @Isanka Wijerathne as the answer, hoping that it will help someone like me. Thank you @Isanka Wijerathne.

1. Which links are going to the localhost? Studio URL, Preview URL, Analytics etc? Then you have to edit "lms.env.json & cms.env.json" and add your host URL, example.com, studio.example.com, preview.example.com.
2. It seems you are using the Open edX devstack version. Isn't it? with this set up I do not think that you can have production like env. Try to install Open edX native installation. But anyway answer to your question is, you have to change the values of those Keys, that I posted previously